# Google Cloud Storage - Public object url e super slow updating

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a bucket with READ permission to allUsers and it's working fine but the public url link `https://storage.googleapis.com/example_bucket/example.png` takes ages to update: if I change the image in storage for a different one with the same name, the bucket view shows the correct image as well as the not public image url `https://storage.cloud.google.com/example_bucket/example.png` however the public url shows the old image and it takes a long time to update. Could someone explain if this is normal or if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: did you happen to find the solution? if any of the the answers provided was useful or the solution, please upvote it or accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [`cache-control`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata#cache-control) when you are uploading the object:

Using `gsutil` when

1. Uploading

`gsutil -D -h Cache-Control:"Cache-Control:private, max-age=0, no-transform" cp file gs://BUCKET/file`

2. Editing: [`gsutil set meta`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/setmeta)

`gsutil setmeta -h Cache-Control:"Cache-Control:private, max-age=0, no-transform" gs://BUCKET/file`

Or through the console:

[image]

Currently, there is no way to set a default `cache-control` for the bucket.

You might be interested in taking a look into this [Viewing / Editing Metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#gsutil)

Answer (score 1):

Objects created with READ permission to allUsers by default are served with `cache-control: public, max-age=3600`. With this cache-control in place updates to the object could not be reflected at caches for an hour.

Comment: How can I modify the cache control value to all present and future objects in the bucket?

Comment: You can update the cache-control header on existing objects using ```gsutil setmeta` - see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/setmeta
To update all future objects you need to set the cache-control header at upload time. Note that cache-control is off if the object is not publicly readable.

Answer (score 0):

I was coming across this same issue while serving up profile images for my users. I fixed this by chaining `?ignoreCache=1` onto the public url.